# What is the grammatical function of はしたが?

Tags: grammar, newspaper-grammar

In this sentence,

司令官【しれいかん】は軍刀【ぐんとう】を手【て】にはしたが、すぐに小野田【おのだ】さんに返【かえ】した

*The commander took the sword in his hand but immediately returned it to Mr. Onoda.*

https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/topics/20240321-OYT8T50062/

What is the grammatical function of はしたが?

Comment: You are parsing it wrong, I think. This is particle は.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is [手にした](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E6%89%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/#je-50666) with は inserted.

は puts focus/emphasis to the whole verb phrase 手にした, so it sounds like *The commander **did take** the sword...* whereas 手にした=*took the sword*.

Comment: A perfect explanation!